# Reading a textstring from a webpage

Tags: c#, text, html

Currently I'm trying to read out a text from a Website via a c# program.
To be exact the Track and the Dj from www.hardbase.fm.

This is what the page source looks like:

```html
<div id="Moderator">
  <div id="Moderator_special">
    <div style="width:158px; float:left; margin:8px"></div>
    <div id="onAir" style="width:420px;overflow:hidden;">
      <strong>
        <a href="/member/46069" target="_top">
          <span style="color:#4AA6E5">BIOCORE</span>
        </a>
        <span style="color:#26628B"> mit "This Is BIOCORE" (Hardstyle)</span>
      </strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text I want to read out is "BIOCORE" and "mit "This Is BIOCORE" (Hardstyle)"
(the text seen when running the snippet).

If have tried the following:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] raw = wc.DownloadData("http://www.hardbase.fm/");
first = webData.IndexOf("#4AA6E5\">") + "#4AA6E5\">".Length;
last = webData.LastIndexOf("</span></a><span style=\"color:#26628B\">");
hb_dj = webData.Substring(first, last - first);
```

But this doesn't always works because sometimes the source code of the page changes a bit. Like the color or so. And then the search wont work.

So the question is: Is there a better method to do this?

Comment: You should look at using the HTML Agility Pack. It provides a more structured way of parsing the DOM of a page. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3):

You should try the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

```
HtmlWeb page = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = page.Load("http://www.hardbase.fm/");

var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id='onAir']");
var nodes2 = nodes.Select(c1 => c1.SelectNodes("span")).ToList();

var span1=nodes2[0];
var span2 nodes2[1]
```

Comment: He can get it by div and  and if there are only two spans but if the pages changes totally then yes it a problem

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating your answer, you may want to add a note on this limitation to it.

Comment: That looks great!
But if I try to run your code, I get the following error:

'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added the using HtmlAgilityPack; and added a reference to the HtmlAgilityPack